# ReactJs, Redux with typescript. Typed combineReducers error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

React app has multiple redux slices and reducers have a signature like following

User reducer:

```
export const user = (
  state: UserState = initialState,
  action: UserAction
): UserState => {
  .....
};
```

Document reducer:

```
export const document = (
  state: DocumentState = initialState,
  action: DocumentAction
): DocumentState => {
  ....
};
```

Action and State types are integrate as follows

```
export type StoreAction = UserAction | DocumentAction;

export type StoreState = {
  user: UserState;
  document: DocumentState;
};
```

Then creating the root reducer like this

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers<StoreState, StoreAction>({
  user,
  document
});
```

This gives erros at each passed reducer

```
(property) document: Reducer<DocumentState, any>
Type '(state: DocumentState | undefined, action: DocumentAction) => DocumentState' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<DocumentState, StoreAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'StoreAction' is not assignable to type 'DocumentAction'.
      Type 'SetUsers' is not assignable to type 'DocumentAction'.
        Type 'SetUsers' is not assignable to type 'ResetDocuments'.
          Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
            Type '"SET_USERS"' is not assignable to type '"RESET_DOCUMENTS"'.ts(2322)
types.ts(9, 3): The expected type comes from property 'document' which is declared here on type 'ReducersMapObject<StoreState, StoreAction>'
```

and

```
(property) user: Reducer<UserState, any>
Type '(state: UserState | undefined, action: UserAction) => UserState' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<UserState, StoreAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'StoreAction' is not assignable to type 'UserAction'.
      Type 'SetDocuments' is not assignable to type 'UserAction'.
        Type 'SetDocuments' is not assignable to type 'ResetUsers'.
          Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
            Type '"SET_DOCUMENTS"' is not assignable to type '"RESET_USERS"'.ts(2322)
types.ts(8, 3): The expected type comes from property 'user' which is declared here on type 'ReducersMapObject<StoreState, StoreAction>'
```

I'm intended to use the `combinedReducer` with signature

```
export function combineReducers<S, A extends Action = AnyAction>(
  reducers: ReducersMapObject<S, A>
): Reducer<CombinedState<S>, A>
```

type of `ReducersMapObjects` seems to be the issue

```
export type ReducersMapObject<S = any, A extends Action = Action> = {
  [K in keyof S]: Reducer<S[K], A>
}
```

Seems like each reducer is suppose to return the `StoreAction`. But that cannot be correct or am I doing something wrong here.

Complete sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-ikucq?file=/src/redux/core/reducer.ts)

Update with first answer.

```
export type StoreAction = UserAction & DocumentAction;
```

This works. But when I apply this to my actual app which as more than 10 slices intersection of all types.

```
export type StoreAction = Actoin1 & Action2 & ... & Action10;
```

This seems too complex because i get error.

```
Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by `OR` operator. You need `AND`

Change this to

```
export type StoreAction = UserAction | DocumentAction;
```

Into

```
export type StoreAction = UserAction & DocumentAction;
```

Updated Answer

You can use [TypeScript tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple)

```
export type StoreAction = [Actoin1, Action2, ..., Action10]
```

Comment: This works in the sample but in my actual app there are mroe than 10 slices. So combining all give me `Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts(2590)` error

Comment: Can't update with same code but I added an example code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you explain why it should be `intersection` rather `union`. Action type is anyof the actions right. So it is the union as I see. Intersection works with how `ReducersMapObject` type is defined. But I wonder whether it is correct.